# How to convert pyarrow.Table to PySpark Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow

I have a `pyarrow.Table` object that I want to pass to PySpark (and save as a Spark table).

How can I convert `pyarrow.Table` to `pyspark.sql.DataFrame`?

The only way I can see it to convert it to `pandas.DataFrame`, but aren't there some more direct and reliable ways?